# How do I have code on one partion execute code on another partition (or SPIFFS) on an ESP32?

Tags: arduino, esp32, platformio

I'm working on an ESP32 based project that will involve OTA flashes of the ESP.

I know that you can set up different partitions on an ESP32. I'm wondering if it's possible for my code on one partition to then execute code on another partition? (For my usage, I don't need data passed back and forth - just execution handed off from one partition to the other and than given back after execution)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you don't have Flash encryption with different keys or other tricky copy protection mechanisms enabled. Partitions on Flash are a completely abstract concept for the developers' peace of mind. The CPU doesn't know and doesn't care - it will execute code from anywhere in Flash if told to jump to it.

The challenge here is that you need to convince the linker to find and call a method from an external, hard-coded address. And you need to make sure said method is actually there :) Since this is not a standard solution, you likely won't find a tutorial but have to know your linker really well :)

There's some useful stuff in the [ESP IDF linker documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/linker-script-generation.html) and probably the GNU linker documentation, if I could find it :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some freeRTOS information.

I will not write any code here but I can give you some ideas on what you are trying to achieve.

Assume you have two tasks and a digital pin, which is pulled high by the setup() function. You define the task handler for each task. Now you want to change the current running program to some other program, you will check if the digital pin has been LOW for 5 seconds if that's the case , you can use the vTaskSuspend() function in the primary task by providing it the handler of your current task and suspend your current task. Be sure to resume your OTA task by vTaskResume() function before calling vTaskSuspend() . When you have completed the update, restart the esp32 by calling ESP.restart().

If you want to abort the OTA task just pull the same digital pin LOW and using the above method in your OTA task also, you can switch back to your primary task.